# How to logout of website during requests session

Tags: python, python-requests

I am attempting to scrape some data from a website which requires a login. To complicate matters, I am scraping data from three different accounts. So in other words, I need to login to the site, scrape the data and then logout, three times.

The html behind the logout button looks like this:
[image: html]

The (very simplified) code I've tried is below:

```
import requests

for account in [account1,account2,account3]:

    with requests.session() as session:

        [[login code here]]

        [[scraping code here]]

        session.get(url + "/logout")
```

The scraping using the first account works fine, but after that it doesn't. I'm assuming this is because I'm not logging out properly. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Don't know if this will work, but try clearing the session cookies using `session.cookies.clear()`. Also are you sure the problem is with serial login and not with any account? Maybe you've tried this, but if not, try changing the order of the accounts in the list. It'll help you debug.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar after or instead of the "session.get(url + "/logout")"?

Comment: Instead of logging out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple:

You should forge correct login request.

To do it go to the login page:

1. open 'Inspect' tool, 'Network' tab. Checking 'Preserve log' option is quite useful as well.
2. Log in to the site, and you'll see login request appeared in Network tab (Usually it's a POST request).
3. Right-click to request, select Copy -> Copy as Curl, and then just use [this brilliant tool](https://curl.trillworks.com/)
4. Usually, you can trim up and headers and cookies of the code produced by the tool(but be careful trimming `Content-Type` header, it can break your code).
5. Replace `requests.[get|post](...)` to `session.[get|post](...)`
6. Profit. You'll have logged in session by execution of the upper code. Logging out and any form population is made pretty much the same way.